# Multiple intervals conflicting in Jquery Object's Instances

Tags: jquery, instance, setinterval, conflict, intervals

I am developing a JQuery plugin that makes use of a interval in each instance of the object.

The problem is that if I create, lets say, three instances only the last interval of the last instance is functionable.

This is the code that sets up the interval:

```
function init()
{
beep();
score=0;
direction = "right";

create_player();
getstats();
drawBackground();
drawCell(player.x,player.y,settings.colors.Stroke);
if(typeof game_loop != "undefined") clearInterval(game_loop);
    game_loop = setInterval(loop, settings.gameSpeed);

}
```

This is the beginning of the object in which I initialize the game_loop as well

```
$.fn.JObject = function(options) 
{

var parent = $(this);
var game_loop;
........
```

This is how I call the Objects

```
$("#screen1").JObject();
$("#screen2").JObject();
$("#screen3").JObject();
```

Shouldn't be that the game_loop is unique for each object I create because it is inside the object's {}?
So why the conflict?

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/0ynv8qhb/4/)**

Comment: It's hard to tell from what you've posted how this all fits together. Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: Its just the game_loop that all this happens in the first box of code. I tested that this is the line. It too much of a code to post.

Comment: What do you mean only the last instance is functionable? What is it supposed to do, and what is it doing instead?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: It uses a drawing loop every some milliseconds to draw data inside a canvas. When I make one instance in the page everything runs ok. If I make multiple instances the first render that happens outside a loop function works as well. But when it comes to the actual loop only the last object renders properly. It seems that they share the same interval but what I want is each instance to have different intervals.

Comment: I created this code in Fiddle that demonstrates the problem. Truth is I am inexperienced with Fiddle and it does not seem to work but you will get the bigger picture.
http://jsfiddle.net/0ynv8qhb/1/

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry. There was no error with the intervals but it was clearly a fault of inproper variable declaration of the canvas context variable ctx.